# One page item renderer magento

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to change template for item renderer on checkout onepage. Here is part from checkout.xml where this renderer is set.

```
    <block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before" as="items_before" translate="label">
            <label>Items Before</label>
        </block>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after" as="items_after" translate="label">
            <label>Items After</label>
        </block>
        <block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/template" name="checkout.onepage.review.button" as="button" template="checkout/onepage/review/button.phtml"/>
    </block>
```

I want to change it for configurable products. I am not sure which solution is the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the item renderer via local.xml file. If the file does not already exist you can create one in `app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/layout/` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_review>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>path/to/your/file/item.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_review>
</layout>
```

You will see why this is possible if you look at `addItemRender` method inside `Mage_Sales_Block_Items_Abstract` class.

```
public function addItemRender($type, $block, $template)
{
    $this->_itemRenders[$type] = array(
        'block'     => $block,
        'template'  => $template,
        'renderer'  => null
    );

    return $this;
}
```

Hope this helps!